# Number of couples of sets with empty intersection in a separating union-closed family of sets

Tags: co.combinatorics

The ratio between the number of unordered couples of sets, with empty intersection between the two sets, and the total number of unordered couples of sets, for a powerset on $n$ elements without the empty set, $\mathcal{P}([n]) \setminus \emptyset$, is:

$$\frac{{n+1 \brace 3}}{{2^n-1 \choose 2}}=\frac{(1 + 3^n - 2^{n+1})}{(2^n-1)(2^n-2)}$$

Where ${n+1 \brace 3}$ denotes a Stirling number of the second kind. Is it possible to find a finite separating union closed family $\mathcal{F}$, $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{F}$, with size of the universe $|U(\mathcal{F})| = n$, with a biconnected Hasse diagram graph (without articulation vertices), and with the ratio defined as above higher than the value for $\mathcal{P}([n]) \setminus \emptyset$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerator grows faster than the denominator, so we can do better by making a minimal extension of a previous powerset: $2^{[k]} \cup \{[m] : k+1 \le m \le n \} \setminus \emptyset$ gives $$\frac{(1 + 3^k - 2^{k+1})}{(2^k+n-k-1)(2^n+n-k-2)}$$ and for $n \ge 5$ the optimal value of $k$ is less than $n$ and grows logarithmically.

```
k    First n for which k is optimal
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    7
6    12
7    24
8    46
9    91
10   182
11   366
```

By brute force enumeration, $2^{[n]} \setminus \emptyset$ is optimal for $n \le 4$.

Comment: Thank you very much, although I am tempted to reformulate the question excluding families such that there does not exist $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$,  $A \not = B$, $A,B \not = U(\mathcal{F})$ such that $A \cup B = U(\mathcal{F})$. I don't know if it is better that I post a new question.

Comment: @BillyJoe, take the construction given and add one set: $[n-2] \cup \{n\}$ to meet the new constraint.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to formalize the concept of a family without "cap", because here we have a smaller union closed family $2^{[k]}$ then "capped" where the abundant elements of $2^{[k]}$ are also abundant elements of $\mathcal{f}$.

Comment: Two approaches which I can see would be to require that each element be in at least $\alpha |\mathcal{F}|$ members of the family, or that each element be in a set of size no more than $\alpha n$. Those may still allow some workarounds. As a separate note, I have a brute force search running for $n=6$ and if the optimal family it finds is better than a "capped" $2^{[4]}$ this may suggest a less objectionable construction.

Comment: I think that the no-"capped" concept can be formalized saying that we exclude families such that there exists an edge in their Hasse diagram such that removing that edge makes the graph disconnected.

Comment: I think that can be worked around by introducing two new elements and then building a "cap" of width three: ${2^{[k]}} \cup {\{[m] : k+2 \le m \le n \}} \cup {\{[m] \setminus \{k+1\} : k+2 \le m \le n \}} \cup {\{[m] \setminus \{k+2\} : k+2 \le m \le n \}} \setminus \emptyset$

Comment: The entry to the wider cap would still be by two edges, so maybe you could say that no vertex in the Hasse diagram may have in-degree 1. But then the same idea can be taken one further to add three new elements in pairs.

Comment: Maybe we exclude families such that there exists a vertex ($\not = U(\mathcal{F})$) in their Hasse diagram such that removing that vertex makes the graph disconnected. In our case it is $[k]$.

Comment: Did the $n=6$ brute force search terminate?

Comment: I've killed it and added more progress logging...

Comment: I have just added the requirement that the Hasse diagram graph cannot have articulation vertices.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that just requires adding $[k-1]\cup\{k+1\}$ and $[k-1]\cup\{k+2\}$.

Comment: @BillyJoe, the brute force search terminated without finding anything better than (compressed format) `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 31, 63]`.